# Formatação de datas em Java

Tags: java, jasper

Boa tarde, tenho um atributo data de um objeto que persisto como string, por precisar dele no formato `ddMMyyyy` em um certo local e também comparar com uma data anterior. Mas em outro momento preciso deste mesmo atributo para gerar um relatório no formato por extenso "dd de mes de ano". O fato é que já procurei fazer isso no dentro do jasper quando chamo o atributo mas não tive exito ainda. o mais próximo que cheguei foi usar substrings para separar os a data mas nao consigo achar uma forma de fazer o mes que está em formato numérico ser apresentado por extenso no relatório. Alguém tem uma sugestão.

Comment: Se puder coloca o código que você está tentando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar formatadores de Datas da própria API do Java, como por exemplo `SimpleDateFormat`

Ex:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format($P{nomeParametro})
```

Ao gerar o relatório pelo próprio [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/), lembre-se de alterar para a `Language` [Java](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MLqwWdqZU6I/U4rz3ywoHYI/AAAAAAAAAGQ/4Sql0A4TrqI/s1600/Capture.PNG).

Após formatar, pode converter de `Date` para `String` e vice versa, caso precisar realizar manipulação da datas.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Valeu Douglas, mas dessa forma exige que tenha um separador na minha string. Li a doc e consegui chegar perto parseando a string e passando com o separador. Mas na hora de por as duas expressoes no jasper deu erro sintaxe.

Comment: Ao parsear para String, não consegue remover os dois separadores? Assim ficaria valido para manipulação de datas com separadores e para mostrar removeria sem separadores.